# dhtmlxtree XML refers to non existing parent

Tags: json, dhtmlx

I am working with dhtmlxtree and are having issues getting it loading data from json fed to it by an external script. I am getting the error below. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
ErrorType: LoadXML
Error: Incorrect JSON
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="treeBox" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;"></div>
   <script>
   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
      tree = new dhtmlXTreeObject("treeBox", "100%", "100%", 0);
      tree.setSkin('dhx_skyblue');
      tree.setImagePath("../sma-js/dhtmlxtree/img/csh_bluebooks/");
      tree.setXMLAutoLoading("sma-php/loadcustomers.php");
      tree.setDataMode("json");
      //load first level of tree;
      tree.loadJSON("sma-php/loadcustomers.php?id=PNR0000000001");
   });
```

When I manually run the script, the JSON returned looks like this:

```
[{"phys_addr_state":"ACT","phys_addr_postcode":"2167","install_address":"2 Eade Street - Radiative, John"},{"phys_addr_state":"NSW","phys_addr_postcode":"2263","install_address":"69 The Corso - Flare, Steve"}, {"phys_addr_state":"NSW","phys_addr_postcode":"2112","install_address":"17 Price Street - Solar, Anita"},{"phys_addr_state":"QLD","phys_addr_postcode":"4001","install_address":"71 Eagle Street - Corona, Linda"},{"phys_addr_state":"VIC","phys_addr_postcode":"3053","install_address":"15 Lygon Street - Photon, Marco"}]
```

The issue I notice is the structure / hierarchy of my JSON. It contains an item per record, whereby other examples I see in dhtml site show a "hierarchical" JSON record. My encode on the server is done by:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

The other dhtml example of JSON (for comparison) is:

```
{ id: 0, item: [{ id: 1, text: "1111" }, { id: 2, text: "222222", item: [{ id: "21", text: "child" }] }, { id: 3,  text: "3333" }]}
```

Is there a different way to encode the sql records whereby all records of same state will be grouped together under the same entry per "id: 2 item above" per example above?

My header includes the following:

```
<script src="../sma-js/d3.v3/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../sma-js/dhtmlxtree/css/dhtmlxtree.css">
<script src="../sma-js/dhtmlxtree/js/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
<script src="../sma-js/dhtmlxtree/js/dhtmlxtree.js"></script>   
<script src="../sma-js/dhtmlxtree/js/dhtmlxtree_json.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use specific JSON format, the same as in dhtmlx demos. However, it would be easier and faster to use [dhtmlxConnector](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxConnector/index.shtml) (free to use with dhtmlx components) instead of custom scripts. The Connector helps to generate XML output, and all you need is to set up table fields for tree XML.